# Centralizar conteúdo em um border CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria que o **Entre/Cadastre-se** ficasse centralizado verticalmente dentro das bordas, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Segue abaixo o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu_2">    
    <div class="user"><li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Entre/Cadastre-se<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></li></div> 
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu_2{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 10pt;  
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #6495ED;
}

.user{
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    height: 49px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `line-height` com a mesma altura do `elemento`

```css
ul {
list-style: none;
}

.menu_2{
padding: 10px;
font-size: 10pt;  
margin-top: 20px;
color: #6495ED;
}

.user{
margin-right: 30px;
font-size: 12pt;
border: 1px solid;
float: left;
height: 49px;
line-height: 49px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="menu_2">    
<div class="user"><li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Entre/Cadastre-se<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></li></div> 
</ul>
```